# compare validation between two (hh:mm:ss a) times in moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have two times with `hh:mm:ss a` format.

like

```
var StartTime="11:50:33 AM";
var EndTime= "10:50:33 AM;
```

I want the validation for `EndTime > StartTime`.

i need compare the two times.

If `StartTime` is greater than `EndTime`, then i want to show a error message

If `EndTime` is greater than `StartTime`, then i want to run next code.

I have tried this below code

```
var t1 = moment($scope.StartTime, "hh:mm:ss a");
            var t2 = moment($scope.EndTime, "hh:mm:ss a");
            var t3 = moment(t2.diff(t1)).format("hh:mm:ss");
```

But this make does not well.

Comment: From a purist perspective, recognize that comparing a time-only value to another time-only value isn't valid.  You need a *date* as well - or at least the constraint that both times are on the *same* day.   Without that constraint, it's a meaningless comparison.  For example, is "12:00 AM" before or after "12:00 PM"?  It depends on whether they are on the same day or not.   Consider that in many cases a time range may cross midnight - such as "10:00 PM - 2:00 AM" being four hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isBefore()` function in Moment.js to check if a date is before another date. See the documentation here. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

**See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3msoff5/) link below.**

**Code**

```
var startTime = moment('11:50:33 AM', 'h:mm:ss a');
var endTime = moment('10:50:33 AM', 'h:mm:ss a');

if(startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
    console.log("Correct. Start Time is below End Time");   
} else {
   console.log("Error. Start Time is more than End Time");
}
```

Comment: As long as we are asserting that both values fall on the same calendar date, and are both *valid* times for that day (not in a DST gap), then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without a library like Moment.js, you might consider writing some simple functions, e.g.

```
var a = '11:50:33 AM';
var b = '10:50:33 AM';

// Times in h:m:s a format
function isStartBeforeEnd(start, end) {
  var dates = [start, end].map(function(time) {
    var b = time.split(/[: ]/);
    return new Date(0,0,0, ((b[0] % 12) + (/^a/i.test(b[3])? 0 : 12)), b[1], b[2])
  })
  return dates[0] < dates[1];
}

console.log(isStartBeforeEnd(a, b)); // false
console.log(isStartBeforeEnd(b, a)); // true
```

Or, probably preferable, if you have a function to reduce the times to some common base, say seconds, you can convert the times to a common base and compare that:

```
// Times in h:m:s a format
function timeToSeconds(time) {
  time = time.split(/[: ]/);
  var hours = (time[0]%12) + (/^a/i.test(time[3]? 0 : 12));
  return hours * 3600 + time[1]*60 + +time[2];
}

console.log(timeToSeconds(a) < timeToSeconds(b)); // false
console.log(timeToSeconds(b) < timeToSeconds(a)); // true
```

Anyhow, just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to first convert it to utc format.

```
moment.utc(moment('11:50:33 AM',"hh:mm:ss a")
.diff(moment("10:50:33","hh:mm:ss a")))
.format("HH:mm:ss a")
```

Comment: The timezone is irrelevant, as long as they are both the same.

Comment: @RobG - Not necessarily.  It's possible that one of the values might fall into the DST gap of a local time zone if ran on the day of a spring-forward DST transition.  :)

Comment: That would be different timezones then.